# Dynamically Loading a UserControl with LoadControl Method (Type, object[])

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to return the html representation of a user/server control through a page method. It works when I call the overload which takes the virtual path to the user control, but not when I try to call the overload which takes a type. The sample code is below. Any suggestions?

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadAlternates(string productId, string pnlId)
{
    object[] parameters = new object[] { pnlId, productId };
    return ControlAsString(typeof(PopupControl), parameters);
}

private static string ControlAsString(Type controlType, object[] parameters)
{
    Page page = new Page();
    UserControl controlToLoad;
    /*
     *calling load control with the type results in the 
     *stringwriter returning an empty string
    */

    controlToLoad = page.LoadControl(controlType, parameters) as UserControl;
    /*
     *However, calling LoadControl with the following overload
     *gives the correct result, ie the string rep. of the control.
    */
     controlToLoad = page.LoadControl(@"~/RepeaterSamples/PopupControl.ascx") as UserControl;

    //some more code, then this... 
    page.Controls.Add(controlToLoad);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, false);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

Any ideas why this StringWriter would return an empty string? I should point out that all the "page" lifecycle execute correctly irrespective of the method chosen to call LoadControl.

Wanted to add -
I *have* to use the `LoadControl(Type, object[])` overload. :-(

Answer (score 25):

On the [MSDN page for LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtd66a0(v=VS.90).aspx#CommunityContent) there is this comment at the bottom:

> Description 
>   A page that loads a user control using the
>   Page.LoadControl(Type, Object[]) does not seem to create its children
>   added in the ascx file. Using Page.LoadControl(String) works as
>   expected.
>
> Comments
>   Thank you for submitting this issue. We're investigating and
>   will provide an update on status when we have more information.
>
> -The Web Platform & Tools Team 
> Posted by Microsoft on 8/06/2005 at 11:08 AM 
> This is by-design since the type "TestUC" is actually the
>   base type used by the partial class, it does not contain the proper
>   code to instantiate TextBox1 reference, which is actually defined in
>   the derived type. There are two workarounds: 1. Use
>   LoadControl("TestControl.ascx"), for all practical, this behaves
>   identically to LoadControl(type) but it instantiates the derived type,
>   which knows how to instantiate TextBox1. 2. Use a single file page and
>   adds <%@ Reference %> directive to the page to reference the user
>   control, and assign a classname to the ascx page. Then it's safe to
>   use LoadControl(type)
>
> Thanks for reporting the issue.
>  Web Platform and Tools Team. Posted by
>   Microsoft on 14/06/2005 at 6:31 PM

Answer (score 7):

That overload instantiates the base class, but doesn't instantiate any of the controls on it, so it doesn't work.

I did a quick [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210413200211/http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/05/passing-parameters-using-loadcontrol/) on a workaround for passing parameters if you're interested.

Comment: Hi, I can pass parameters to the control in either case. But I have to load controls using the control type.

Comment: You can't use parameters with the string method.. but that doesn't really help if you need to do it by type. Why do you need to use the other overload? The only thing I can think of is reflect on the working overload and replicate what it does in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the control completely rendered one way to do this is to instantiate the control as you are now with `LoadControl` and then temporarily add it to the control collection of another control or the page itself.  This will initialize the life-cycle for that control and cause all of the proper events to be raised.  Once you have done this then you can get the rendered HTML or whatever you need from it.

Yes, this is a hack but it will work in a pinch.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're saying, but isn't he already adding the control to a page's controls collection: <pre><code>
page.Controls.Add(controlToLoad);
</code></pre>

Comment: I know this answer was from *ages* ago, but could you elaborate Andrew? Or point me to a write up on this workaround? I'm trying to use `LoadControl` with a type param, with my intention being to add the loaded control to a `PlaceHolder` anyway, so it's not that much of a hack for me. To be honest, magic strings with paths to controls (the alternative) seems like more of a hack to me! Thanks in advance.